# How can I limit the number of post in home page?

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

I am facing a problem to show limited number of post in home page.

```
     I want to show 2 posts in home page then pagination link (older post-->>        Newer Post-->)
```

I am using this code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=2&paged=' . $paged);

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

And it shows 2 posts in home but when I clicked Next post-->> Then Only 3 pages shows

But I have 24 posts so it should shows 12 pages

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I am using this function for pagination

function content_nav( $nav_id ) {

 global $wp_query;


 if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
  <div id="<?php echo $nav_id; ?>">

    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( ' Older posts  <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>','test' )); ?></div>
   <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Newer posts', 'test' )); ?></div>
   



  </div><!-- #nav-above -->
 <?php endif;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just use the arg "post_per_page" in your WP_Query()

codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters